# Initializer element is not a compile-time constant when multiplying constants, C++

Tags: c++, xcode, program-entry-point, initializer

I have this code here

```
//GLOBAL 
//  Power Demand in St John's per year [GJ/yr]
double P_year = 14367865E9;
double s_year = 365*24*60*60;// Seconds in a year [s]

//  Power Demand in St John's per second [GJ/yr]
double P_s = P_year*(1/s_year);
//electric permitivitty of free space [s4A2/m3kg]
double epsilon = 8.85418782E-12;

int main(){
    
// Energy Required for 6hrs demand [J]
    double E = P_s * 60*60*6;
// Voltage Difference accross capacitor [V]
    double V = 230E3;

// Capacitance
    double C = 2*E/pow(V,2);
    
    printf("%f %f \n", E, C);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Capacitor.c:11:20: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
double P_s = P_year*(1/s_year);
```

I do not understand why it won't just multiply it.
Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: Maybe spricle a bit of `const` or `constexpr`..

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/Wh5v4oGjM), once I put the necessary includes in. But depending on where you're actually using `P_s` in a context that requires it to be a compile-time constant, as Jesper suggests you can just declare the relevant variables `const` or `constexpr`.

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?  [I cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/W85Tehv6T)

Comment: Based on the filename, it looks ilike this is C, not C++.

Comment: Just added const prior the variable definitions and that worked! Thank you all.